# how to import all icons in Material Design from react-icons

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app, react-icons

I could not find anywhere in the documentation and on google how to use

import * as MaterialDesign from "react-icons/"

in the render fonction.

Thank you for understanding.

Comment: Yes, I want to import all Material icons.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To include all icons in one; You must use this code!

```
import * as MaterialDesign from "react-icons/md";
```

To use an icon:  ( <MaterialDesign.IconName /> )

```
<MaterialDesign.MdHelp />
```

***Note:** Make sure you have installed the react-icons package!*

Answer (score 0):

That's a lot of bloat to import all those icons in a project. If you're trying to get *just the library for Material Design icons* you can use something like [`@react-md/material-icons`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@react-md/material-icons).

### Installation

```
yarn add @react-md/material-icons @react-md/icon
```

### Usage

```
import { render } from "react-dom";

import {
  AccessAlarmFontIcon,
  AccessAlarmSVGIcon,
  Rotation3DFontIcon, // the sprite name for this was 3d_rotation.svg
  Rotation3DSVGIcon, // the sprite name for this was 3d_rotation.svg
  HomeFontIcon,
  HomeSVGIcon,
} from "@react-md/material-icons";

const App = () => (
  <main>
    <AccessAlarmFontIcon />
    <AccessAlarmSVGIcon />
    <Rotation3DFontIcon />
    <Rotation3DSVGIcon />
    <HomeFontIcon />
    <HomeSVGIcon />
  </main>
);

render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

[Github](https://github.com/mlaursen/react-md)

Or just use

```
yarn add @material-ui/core @material-ui/icons
```

then call the icon

```
import MenuIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Menu'
```

and in your component just add `<MenuIcon/>`. There is a way to search for any [Material Icon](https://mui.com/material-ui/material-icons/).

Comment: this not work for me, because I need auto-generate icons from material design, anyway thank you.